# What does ${ARGUMENT+x} mean in Bash?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that uses the following syntax:

```
if [ ! -z ${ARGUMENT+x} ]; then
```

What is the meaning of the "+x" syntax after the argument name?

Comment: @Benjamin W. Yes, it's the same question, but I didn't found it because it's intended for "plus colon". That was not my issue. My issue was about arguments, not "plus colon".

Comment: Both questions are about parameter expansion with `+`; it doesn't matter what comes after the `+`, so in my opinion, they are duplicates.

Comment: Ok. But anyway I didn't found that question, so it means that everyone is looking for "argument" with "+x" will never find that question, they will find my question.

Comment: That's fine - it's now a signpost pointing to the other question.

Comment: Using `[ ! -z "…" ]` is a long-winded and devious/obscure way of writing `[ -n "…" ]`.  The first checks for not zero length, but so does the second, without the additional operator.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It means that if `$ARGUMENT` is set, it will be replaced by the string `x`

### Let's try in a shell :

```
$ echo  ${ARGUMENT+x}

$ ARGUMENT=123
$ echo  ${ARGUMENT+x}
x
```

You can write this with this form too :

```
${ARGUMENT:+x}
```

It have a special meaning with `:`, it test that variable is empty **or** unset

Check [bash *parameter expansion*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters)

Comment: Very exhaustive answer.

Comment: "*You can write this with this form too*", but then it does something different.

Comment: Yes, post edited accordingly

Comment: This is exactly wrong, it will be replaced with `x` if the variable is set. The parameter expansion operator `-` interpolates a value if something is unset.

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Comment: Oh, why does bash need to be so esoteric?

Answer (score 16):

Rather than discussing the syntax, I'll point out what it is attempting to do: it is trying to deterimine if a variable `ARGUMENT` is set to any value (empty or non-empty) or not. In `bash` 4.3 or later, one would use the `-v` operator instead:

```
if [[ -v ARGUMENT ]]; then
```

Comment: Ah ok, so this is equivalent. Nice to know. In effect that was a pretty old script, but I didn't know the syntax.

Comment: In isolation, these are equivalent, but you can use `${var+x}` anywhere you can use `$var` so it can be part of a more complex expression, perhaps involving multiple variables etc.

Comment: Note that "modern `bash`" here specifically means version `>=4.3`.

Comment: Yeah, saying "modern" instead of providing a specific version was a dumb idea.